# Preserve special characters in QueryDict from Form (Django)

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, post

My template has a simple form that is returned to Django with an XMLHttpRequest.

The form:

```
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="return false;"  accept-charset="UTF-8" >{% csrf_token %}  
     <p><label for="dev_Ser">Device info:</label>
     <input type="text"  id="dev_Ser"name="devSerial" maxlength="100" /></p>
      <input id="subBut" type="submit" />  
   </form>
```

The back-and-forth communication is working fine, but the form field needs to allow entry of special characters like % and &.

When I examine the QueryDict from the POST that arrives at the Django server, the special characters have been lost.

in Django, I use:

```
print( str(request.POST) )
```

and if my form contained "hello%64", Django tells me it sees:

```
<QueryDict: {u'device': [u'hellod'] }>
```

I must be missing something. Do I need to do something in javascript to encode the content of that text input before POSTing it off to my Django server?

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing like posting a question to make you discover the answer quickly yourself.  Adding here for others who might stumble across this.

When I encapsulate my form's text entries to send via XMLHttpRequest, I can use javascript's encodeURIComponent() function to encode the contents and thus preserve them for Django's handling.

Thus, the QueryDict shows that the characters come through properly and I get my "hello%64" as I required.

Cheers.